# How can I use two angular data-tables on the same angular controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, datatables, angular-datatables

I have a datatable. When I click on a row of the datatable a bootstrap modal pops up and among other things there is another datatable inside. However I can't make it work. No datatable shows up when the modal pops up and no errors appear on the console. I used ng-repeat with datatables because the async method was not working through https and this approach allowed me to customize the tr element more easily.

controller.js:

```
...
var vm = this;

vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions();

vm.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0), // ProjectID
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1), // Name
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3), // Priority
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4), // Status
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5), // ProjectManager
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(6), // Contract
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(7) // Description
];

vm.quotationsOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions();
vm.quotationsCollumns = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(8), // Number
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(9), // Phase
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(10), // Reason
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(11) // Date
];

$scope.openModal = function (p) {
    $scope.selectedContractID = p.ContractID;
    $scope.projectModal = p;
    $scope.quotationsModal = [];
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < p.Quotations.length; i++) {
        $http
            .get("http://localhost:63680/api/quotations/" + p.Quotations[i])
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.doesProjectHaveQuotations = true;
                $scope.quotationsModal.push(response.data);
                $scope.quotationsModal.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a.ID - b.ID;
                });
            });
    }
};
```

index.html

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-12" id="data-tables">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Projects
                <small>Overview</small>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <table datatable="ng" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumnDefs"
               class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project ID</th>
                    <th>Contract</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Project Manager</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="p in projects" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-quotation"
                    ng-click="openModal(p)" )>
                    <td>{{ p.ProjectID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ p.Contract }}</td>
                    <td>{{ p.Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ p.Status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ p.Priority }}</td>
                    <td>{{ p.ProjectManager }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-quotation" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Project's Quotations</h4>
                <h5 class="modal-title" style="margin-top: 10px"><b>Name: </b>{{ projectModal.Name }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table datatable="ng" dt-options="showCase.quotationsOptions" dt-columns="showCase.quotationsCollumns" class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Project ID:
                                            <span class="notBold">{{ projectModal.ProjectID }}</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Contract:
                                            <span class="notBold">{{ projectModal.Contract }}</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Status:
                                            <span class="notBold">{{ projectModal.Status }}</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Priority:
                                            <span class="notBold">{{ projectModal.Priority }}</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Project Manager:
                                            <span class="notBold">{{ projectModal.ProjectManager }}</span>
                                        </th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-responsive" ng-if="doesProjectHaveQuotations">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Number</th>
                                        <th>Phase</th>
                                        <th>Reason</th>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="q in quotationsModal" ng-click="quotationIsSelected(q)">
                                        <td>{{ q.Number }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ q.PhaseName }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ q.ReasonName }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ q.Date | date}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="!doesProjectHaveQuotations">
                            <p style="text-align: center;">This project doesn't currently have any quotations.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-click="addQuotation()">Add
                    Quotation
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-click="projectDetails()">Details
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how I can fix this. Since there are no errors I'm not sure where the problem is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the code for `openModal()`, and the whole markup for the modal would be great as well.

Comment: @davidkonrad I have updated my question to feature the code you have asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was happening. I was retrieving rows from the server one by one and initializing the data table each time I got one which would give me the "3. Warning: Cannot reinitialise Datatable".

So what I did was create a temporary variable where I would store all my rows and, after making sure I had retrieved all rows from the server I would point the ng-model of the table to that variable and it worked.